# Singleton Sets Not Open

Tags: general-topology

I working on a proof which required that no singleton set $\{x\}$ in a topological space $X$ be open. I was wondering if this is equivalent to a standard topological property? Or maybe a combination of properties?

Comment: This seems to be an unusual property – the only discrete space with this property is empty...

Comment: If the space is connected and Hausdorff, no singleton can be open ..... (assuming that there are at least 2 points, I mean)

Comment: Interesting. This raises another interesting question. You couldn't have a connected Housdorff with two points, or even finite, I think. Could you have a connected Hausdorff space with a countable number of points? I'll ask this as a separate question.

Comment: @AlexS: One nice page (about which I learned on this site) is http://topology.jdabbs.com/ There you can search for for examples of topological spaces with given properties. At least if you find a space with a set of given properties using this site, you know that the properties are compatible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *is* a standard topological property: such a space is said to be [*dense-in-itself*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense-in-itself) or [*perfect*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_set).

- Every connected $T_1$-space with more than one point is perfect.
- Every space that is meagre (first category) in itself is perfect.
- Every Cartesian product of infinitely many non-trivial spaces is perfect.
- Every homogeneous space that isn’t discrete is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

An open singleton is also called an [isolated point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_point). A topological space with no isolated points is called a [perfect space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_set_(mathematics)).